# How can I toggle the main menu visibility using the Alt key in WPF?

Tags: wpf, menu, keyboard-shortcuts, toggle, visibility

I'd like the main menu in my WPF app to behave like the main menu in IE8:

- it's not visible when the app starts
- pressing and releasing Alt makes it visible
- pressing and releasing Alt again makes it invisible again
- repeat until bored

How can I do this?  Does it have to be code?

*Added in response to answers submitted, because I'm still having trouble:*

My Shell code-behind now looks like this:

```
public partial class Shell : Window
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsMainMenuVisibleProperty;

    static Shell()
    {
        FrameworkPropertyMetadata metadata = new FrameworkPropertyMetadata();
        metadata.DefaultValue = false;

        IsMainMenuVisibleProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "IsMainMenuVisible", typeof(bool), typeof(Shell), metadata);
    }

    public Shell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.PreviewKeyUp += new KeyEventHandler(Shell_PreviewKeyUp);
    }

    void Shell_PreviewKeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.SystemKey == Key.LeftAlt || e.SystemKey == Key.RightAlt)
        {
            if (IsMainMenuVisible == true)
                IsMainMenuVisible = false;
            else
                IsMainMenuVisible = true;
        }
    }

    public bool IsMainMenuVisible
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsMainMenuVisibleProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsMainMenuVisibleProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

Comment: You want to mimic Internet Explorer...?

Comment: I try to keep my apps consistent with what users expect,  so yes.  :-)

Comment: Might as well account for F10 key triggering the same behavior for consistency.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `PreviewKeyDown` event on the window. To detect the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key you will need to check the `SystemKey` property of the `KeyEventArgs`, as opposed to the Key property which you normally use for most other keys.

You can use this event to set a `bool` value which has been declared as a `DependencyProperty` in the windows code behind.

The menu's `Visibility` property can then be bound to this property using the `BooleanToVisibilityConverter`.

```
<Menu 
    Visibility={Binding Path=IsMenuVisibile, 
        RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window},
        Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}
    />
```

Comment: I can't get this working.  I've updated the original question with the code-behind for my DependencyProperty.  It's the first time I've declared my own so... 
I've added your binding to the Menu in Shell.xaml and the error I'm getting is: 
System.Windows.Data Error: 39 : BindingExpression path error: 'IsMenuVisibile' property not found on 'object' ''Shell' (Name='')'. BindingExpression:Path=IsMenuVisibile; DataItem='Shell' (Name=''); target element is 'Menu' (Name='uxMainMenu'); target property is 'Visibility' (type 'Visibility').  Any ideas?

Comment: This is the standard binding error you get when the property can't be found. To fix it you need to replace IsMenuVisible with IsMainMenuVisible in your binding.

Comment: Oh, I am such an idiot!  I'll log in and sort it out.  Thanks.  And thanks for not pointing out how thick I am.  :-)

Comment: That was exactly it.  Thanks very much.  Not only have I implemented (thanks to you) the Alt-key functionality AND my first DependencyProperty but I've also painted two ceilings today: I think I'll quite now, whilst I'm ahead.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

I just came across this problem myself. I tried hooking into the `PreviewKeyDown` event, but found it to be unreliable. Instead I found the `InputManager` class where you can hook into the `EnterMenuMode` from managed code. The manager exposes two events, for enter and exit. The trick is to not collapse the menu, but set it's container height to zero when it is to be hidden. To show it, simply clear the local value and it will take its previous height.

From my `TopMenu` user control:

```
public TopMenu()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    InputManager.Current.EnterMenuMode += OnEnterMenuMode;
    InputManager.Current.LeaveMenuMode += OnLeaveMenuMode;
    Height = 0;
}

private void OnLeaveMenuMode(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Height = 0;
}

private void OnEnterMenuMode(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    ClearValue(HeightProperty);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd try looking into handling the `PreviewKeyDown` event on your window. I'm not sure if pressing Alt triggers this event or not, but if it does, then I'd toggle a `bool` which is bound to the visibility of the main menu of the window.

If `PreviewKeyDown` doesn't work, I'm not sure what else to try. You could look into getting at the actual Windows messages sent to your window, but that could get messy very quickly.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I'm going with Phil Price's suggestion of PreviewKeyUp because that's closer to IE but otherwise it sounds doable.

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to use [`GetKeyboardState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646299(VS.85).aspx) with `VK_MENU` to handle both left and right <kbd>Alt</kbd>, to mimic the behavior of IE / Windows Explorer (Vista+) you'll need to track the previously focused element to store focus, on a `VK_MENU` press whilst the focused element is within your main menu. You also want to be doing this work on `PreviewKeyUp` (not down).

Comment: Thanks.  At the mo, I can't even get the basics going so I'll leave WM stuff for a bit!

Answer (score 1):

See my answer to the following thread:
[How to make WPF MenuBar visibile when ALT-key is pressed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6679197/how-to-make-wpf-menubar-visibile-when-alt-key-is-pressed/61267375#61267375)

There I describe how to solve your problem with the class [**`InputManager`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.inputmanager?view=netcore-3.1) (from namespace `System.Windows.Input`).

You can register the classes events `EnterMenuMode` and `LeaveMenuMode`.