# Hidden Main Menu in a delphi program, automatically shown using Alt key

Tags: delphi, menu, delphi-xe

First, let me say that I abominate this feature in Windows Vista and Windows 7.  Second, I want to do it.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218394/how-can-i-toggle-the-main-menu-visibility-using-the-alt-key-in-wpf) is a question asking how to do what I want here,  in WPF.

I want to do the same thing, but in Delphi, using VCL stock components, TMainMenu or Action Manager menus, or some available third party components, even Toolbar2000 or some other library.

Feature of Windows Vista/Windows 7 explorer main-menus:

- it's not visible when the app starts
- pressing and releasing Alt makes it visible
- pressing and releasing Alt again makes it invisible again
- repeatable.
- hotkeys work on menu items, even when menu is invisible*

(* Windows Explorer Hotkeys Example: Ctrl+A in Microsoft Windows Explorer selects all even when the menus are invisible, Alt+T = bring up Tools popup menu, even when the whole menu is hidden).

[image]

**Update:** Demo using accepted answer can be downloaded [here](https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=f5bb35ae00415bc7&sc=documents&id=F5BB35AE00415BC7!245#). (HiddenMenu.zip)

Comment: There are lots of features in Windows Explorer that I abominate. hide extensions for known/registered file types, "simplified file sharing", and the 9-levels-deep you need to go into dialogs to change the NTFS file permissions are some of my "least favorites". :-)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use a `TMainMenu` with a `TActionList` as usual.

Then do

```
procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Self.Menu := nil;
end;
```

(or simply remove the `Menu` association at design time) and

```
procedure TForm1.FormKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
  Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  if (Key = VK_MENU) or (Key = VK_F10) then
    Menu := MainMenu1;
end;
```

and

```
procedure TForm1.WndProc(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  inherited;
  case Message.Msg of
    WM_EXITMENULOOP:
      SetMenu(Handle, 0);
  end;
end;
```

Don't forget to set the form's `KeyPreview` to `true`.

(Notice that, since the shortcuts are handled by the `TActionList`, they work even if the menu is 'gone'.)

Comment: @David: Not as nice as one would like... It seems like the action isn't fired if you click the menu item. I am working on it...

Comment: Not sure, but isn't there a `Key := 0;` missing inside the if-clause in FormKeyDown?

Comment: @Uwe: No, you want the default behaviour as well.

Comment: *'pressing and **releasing** Alt makes it visible'*. Though it will probably be no problem to replace `OnKeyDown` with `OnKeyUp`.