# Key press getting lost in menu loop

Tags: delphi

I want to build a menu form that acts similar to ribbon keytips - you can

- press and hold <kbd>Alt</kbd>, then press and release e. g. <kbd>d</kbd>, then release <kbd>Alt</kbd> to trigger an action or
- press and release <kbd>Alt</kbd>, then press and release <kbd>d</kbd> to trigger the same action

I took inspiration at [Hidden Main Menu in a delphi program automatically shown using Alt key](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6469398/1431618) and came up with the following demo:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows,
  Messages,
  SysUtils,
  Variants,
  Classes,
  Graphics,
  Controls,
  Forms,
  Dialogs,
  ImgList,
  StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Label1: TLabel;
    procedure FormKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
  strict private
    FShowKeyTips: Boolean;

    procedure UpdateKeyTipState(AShowKeyTips: Boolean);
    procedure WMExitMenuLoop(var Message: TMessage); message WM_EXITMENULOOP;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses
  ShellAPI,
  Menus;

{ TForm1 }

constructor TForm1.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  Label1.Caption := 'Dummy';
end;

destructor TForm1.Destroy;
begin
  inherited Destroy;
end;

procedure TForm1.WMExitMenuLoop(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  UpdateKeyTipState(False);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
const
  MAPVK_VK_TO_CHAR = 2;

  // Adapted from dxBar.pas:
  function IsTextCharForKeyTip(AKey: Word): Boolean;
  var
    ARes: UINT;
  begin
    ARes := MapVirtualKey(AKey, MAPVK_VK_TO_CHAR);
    Result := ((ARes and $FFFF0000) = 0) and (Char(ARes) <> ' ') and (Char(ARes) in [#32..#255]);
  end;

var
  hk: string;
  CheckKeyTips: Boolean;
begin
  if (Key = VK_MENU) or (Key = VK_F10) then
  begin
    UpdateKeyTipState(True);
    Exit;
  end;

  if FShowKeyTips then
    CheckKeyTips := True
  else
    CheckKeyTips := Shift = [ssAlt];
  if CheckKeyTips and IsTextCharForKeyTip(Key) then
  begin
    hk := Char(Key); // TODO: Handle analogouos to TdxBarItemLink.IsAccel?
    if SameText(hk, 'd') then
    begin
      Caption := Caption + '+';
      Key := 0;
      Exit;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.UpdateKeyTipState(AShowKeyTips: Boolean);
begin
  if FShowKeyTips = AShowKeyTips then
    Exit;

  FShowKeyTips := AShowKeyTips;
  if AShowKeyTips then
    Label1.Caption := 'Dummy (d)'
  else
    Label1.Caption := 'Dummy';
end;

end.
```

(Create a standard VCL app, add Label1 to Form1 and replace the contents of Unit1.pas with the above.)

The first bullet point works (adds a + to the form caption), however I can't make the second one work. I can't find where the <kbd>d</kbd> gets handled. I tried WM_(SYS)KEYDOWN, CM_DIALOGCHAR and more to no avail.

Any ideas?

Comment: For future consideration, instead of trying random handlers it's easier to override wndproc and dump messages and parameters.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz, good idea! Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms647553(v=vs.85).aspx#_win32_Standard_Keyboard_Interface) the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key, when pressed and released alone, *"toggles in and out of menu bar mode*". This is true even if your form does not have a window menu, the system menu is sufficient for the system to put the window into a modal menu loop. In this mode a non-accelerator will generate a [`WM_MENUCHAR`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646349(v=vs.85).aspx) message:

> Sent when a menu is active and the user presses a key that does not
>   correspond to any mnemonic or accelerator key.

This is the message that you're looking for, read the character from the `User` field. And you don't have to track the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key, since the window being in a modal menu loop means the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key has been pressed once. Otherwise a key down message is generated instead of a menu character message.

Note that if your form does not have a system menu (in `BorderIcons` uncheck `biSystemMenu`) and a window menu, a regular `WM_KEYDOWN` will be sent which you're already handling.