# How to capture a key pressed event while a menu item is highlighted (in Lazarus)

Tags: menuitem, lazarus, platform-independent

In Lazarus, I want to programmatically delete a menu item (say under the **File** menu) during runtime. The user will open the **File** menu to list all its items, then use the arrow keys to go to a specific (*deletable*) item, like a recently used file, and press <kbd>Del</kbd> key to delete that menu item from the **File** menu.

***How can I capture the event of <kbd>Del</kbd> key being pressed while a specific menu item is selected (highlighted) by the user?***

Please note that I am coding for both Windows and Linux (*GTK2*) at the same time. So, I would need a "standard" (*Lazarus-way* of) solution that will work on both systems: Suggested Windows-related answers are not appropriate in my case.

Comment: This might help here https://stackoverflow.com/a/49455070/49925

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Key press getting lost in menu loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49451207/key-press-getting-lost-in-menu-loop)

Comment: You will most likely not find an answer that works for both platforms as the way menus are handled are very different. So some conditional compilation is in order. The comments above should give you the answer for Windows.